Увеличить скорость мыши на Linux
lena@lena-desktop:~$ xinput list
WARNING: running xinput against an Xwayland server. See the xinput man page for details.
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:15                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:15              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer-gestures:15              id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:15                      id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]

Скорость мыши стоит на максимуме, недостаточно. Пытаюсь разобраться как увеличить ее еще.
Собственно, список устройств, вижу клавиатуру причем их 2 а на самом деле одна, скоторой пишу.
Какая из них мышь, какой ее id?
Вычитала
xinput set-prop 'id' 276 3.0

Это уменьшает скорость мыши, как будет если увеличить в 2 раза -2.0. Так что ли, в минус это плюс, а плюс это минус?

Ну как минимум использовать xinput в Wayland автоматически бессмысленно

Не понимаю, можно пожалуйста пошагово написать, что необходимо выполнить. Приобрела себе расбери пи5 и пытаюсь освоить линукс. Убунту...

очевидно же, если 3.0 уменьшает скорость в три раза, то для увеличения в два раза должно быть значение 0.5, а -2.0 - это двигать мышь в противоположную сторону.
